# Batch script dependent on qBitTorrent's obsolete .unwanted directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, bittorrent

I have this script that continuously monitors a `Downloads` directory for completed downloads. One of many programs used to populate this directory is `qBitTorrent`. It determines the torrent subdirectories as complete if they do not include any `.!qB` temp files. Now if some of the files from the torrent were unchecked/skipped from downloading then the forever incomplete `.!qB` files used to go to the `.unwanted` directory which could simply be deleted to determine this, but after `v4.3.0` the `.unwanted` directory was dropped and now the skipped files will forever look like they are in progress so the torrent will never appear complete to the script, rendering my entire script defective.

What in the world could I do to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the client to keep in-progress torrent data a diffent directory and only move it to the download directory once a torrent is finished.

This way your script will only notice the download once it's complete.